# Jenkins "Git plugin" neither ignores commits with certain messages nor commits with from certain users

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, build-process

I am using Jenkins "**Git plugin**" to poll my git repository for commits.
I have been using the "**Advanced behavior**" options "**polling ignores commits from certain users","polling ignores commits with certain messages", as well as "polling ignores commits in certain paths".**
These seemed to work with an earlier version of Jenkins and the Git Plugin.

But I had, for some reasons ,started with a fresh instance of Jenkins and now, even though I am using the latest version of the plugin, the polling triggers a build for all commits, even if it is supposed to ignore them.

My Jenkins job does a git commit after the job has completed,which in turn triggers another build(even though i have ignored them via all the "**Advanced behavior**" options").

As a result, I have a series of unwanted builds triggered.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is a current fix in progress at [JENKINS-25048](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25048), with [PR 318](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/318)

That could be enough for git polling to ignores what it is supposed to.

Note: there is a [similar bug with pipelines](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36195).

Comment: Are you suggesting that this has been there for a long time?

Comment: @ashu Apparently, those bugs are seen again with more recent implementation of Jenkins (2.x)

Comment: @ashu With the same version of Jenkins?

Comment: @ashu If the version of Jenkins is the same, then it must be something specific to the git repos.

Comment: no,different one.Also I have two similar job,with the same configurations but for different repositories, but only one is having this problem.

Comment: @ashu What is the version of each Jenkins?

Comment: The current has version 2.9, and the older one had 1.626.I don't think the jenkins version could have caused the problem here, as I have two jobs having similar configurations, polling from similar repositories but having different behavior for ignoring.

Comment: @ashu same git version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116651/discussion-between-ashu-and-vonc).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the plugin is not filtering your commits (which have to be ignored); and hence triggers a build on these commits.

Check the regex to filter specific commits that you have set in the plugin.

Comment: I had the same regex working for the earlier instance,so I guess this should not be the problem in this scenario

Answer (score -2):

It seems that Jenkins "polling ignores commits from certain users","polling ignores commits with certain messages" and "polling ignores commits in certain paths" ignores the merge commits.
Also it seems that even the changelogs does not have any "merge" commits.